# Enable Jasper Studio Webservice plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I have a problem installing [Jasper Studio Webservice plugin](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/web-service-data-source/releases) in Eclipse Neon. I followed the instructions in [Installing the Webservice Datasource](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/installing-webservice-datasource), where in simple words what I need to do is to copy the jars:

- com.jaspersoft.studio.data.webservice.google.jar
- com.jaspersoft.studio.webservice.connectors.elasticsearch.jar
- com.jaspersoft.studio.data.webservice.WebService.jar

And paste them within the eclipse/plugins folder, but the adapter is not displaying how is depicted in the [Webservice Datasource Documentation](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/webservice-datasource-documentation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After awhile searching in Google I ended up following these answers, but none of these worked for me:

- [Eclipse: How to install a plugin manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31553376/eclipse-how-to-install-a-plugin-manually)
- [Easy way to copy old plugins into new install of eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438529/easy-way-to-copy-old-plugins-into-new-install-of-eclipse)

What it worked was search in the [Eclipse Documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fp2_dropins_format.html) that describes that for old plugins you have to put them in eclipse/dropins folder.